# How to implement delegate protocol between two NSViewControllers which are managed by an NSSplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-yosemite

I'm new to Mac OS X development, I know how to work with protocols in iOS apps development and I understand how they work.

Now I have a small project which has an `NSSplitViewController` with two `NSSplitViewItems`, and which has relationships with `NSViewController`, `ProjectsVC`, and `TasksVC`. I am using Xcode 6 with storyboards.

[image: NSSplitViewController]

In ProjectsVC I have this protocol

```
@protocol ProjectsVCDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)didSelectedProject:(JTProject*)project;

@end
```

The question is, how to get instance of ProjectsVC in TasksVC to set delegate to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you think about problems like this think about how to keep things decoupled.  One way would be to have your Split View Controller manage the relationship.  Just like your ProjectsVC acts as a delegate for a JTProject, your Split View Controller can act as a delegate for your Projects VC.  You can call a method letting the SVC know something occurred that it might care about, and then it can do something in response, like call a method on TasksVC that would do something.

Benefits: ProjectsVC doesn't know anything about TasksVC, TasksVC doesn't know anything about ProjectsVC.  They are managed by an object that is allowed to use those resources to accomplish more complex domain tasks.

Example (Letting Split View Controller implement ProjectVCDelegate and ProjectsVC having an assign property projectVCDelegateForward that the Split View Controller assigns itself to.

```
// ProjectsVC
-(void)didSelectedProject:(JTProject*)project {
    [self.projectCVDelegateForward didSelectedProject: project];
}


// Split View Controller
-(void)didSelectedProject:(JTProject*)project {
    [self.tasksVC doSomethingRelatedToSelectedProject: project];
}
```

Comment: (You can call a method letting the "SVC" know something) what is SVC? and can you give an example of code?

Comment: Split View Controller